# I want to execute function when app gets remove from stack in ionic3

Tags: cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I want to call function just before app gets remove from stack in ionic3 app for android and IOS.

I have already tried platform **"pause"** and **"resume"** methods but it not works well when we remove app from stack.

Is there any solution for that ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

`ionViewWillLeave() {
    // Your Action Here
  }`

to perform an action before page leaves,

you can read more here [Lifecycle events for Ionic 3](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/)

Comment: Sorry but its not working actually i want to call function when app gets remove from device application stack not from navigation stack :)

Comment: okay, you need to use the `Platform` package then. In your `app.component.ts` you can listen to it this way `platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
    //inside the app
    //what you need to do
});`

Comment: Yes, I tested that and it's working when we put app in background but it doesn't subscribe when we exit app.